# RegexIterator filter images, ignore specific directory

Tags: php

**::SOLUTION::**

using @RomanPerekhrest answer with a slight modification, I have what I need.  This adds multiple directories to search recursively, while filtering out certain folders (in my case: "_thumbs" folders).  Final code below:

```
$dir1 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder01");
$dir2 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder02");
$dir3 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder03");
$iterators = new AppendIterator();

$filter = function ($file, $key, $iterator) {
    if ($iterator->hasChildren() && $file->getFilename() != "_thumbs") {
        return true;
    }
return $file->isFile();
};

$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir1 ));
$iterators->append( $dir2 );
$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($dir3, $filter)));

$rgIt = new RegexIterator($iterators, "/^.+\.jpg$/i");
$files = iterator_to_array($rgIt);
```

---

**::Original Question::**

I'm having a tough time figuring out the RegexIterator.  I'm trying to filter out a directory thats inside a parent directory that's been scanned by RecursiveIteratorIterator.  In my code below, $dir3 has multiple directories, hence the RecursiveIteratorIterator, however it also has a "_thumbs" directory, which I don't want it to process.  The RegexIterator currently is filtering and keeping .jpg images, but I'd like to also kill anything that was grabbed from the "_thumbs" directory.

```
$dir1 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder01");
$dir2 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder02");
$dir3 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder03"); // <<< this dir has a _thumbs directory that I don't want to process
$iterators = new AppendIterator();

$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir1 ));
$iterators->append( $dir2 );
$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir3 ));

$rgIt = new RegexIterator($iterators, "/^.+\.jpg$/i");  //<<< this filters and keeps .jpg images.  I don't fully understand the syntax though
$files = iterator_to_array($rgIt);


usort($files, function($a, $b){
    if(filectime($a) == filectime($b)){
        return 0;
    }
    return filectime($a) > filectime($b) ? -1 : 1;
});

$files = array_slice($files, 0 , 18);
```

---

**::EDIT01::**

Here's another test I tried, but also didn't get anywhere with it.  Tried using RecursiveFilterIterator, but I doubt I'm using it correctly.  The error I get says "`Argument 1 passed to RecursiveFilterIterator::__construct() must implement interface RecursiveIterator, instance of AppendIterator given`".

```
$dir1 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder01");
$dir2 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder02");
$dir3 = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./folder03");
$iterators = new AppendIterator();

$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir1 ));
$iterators->append( $dir2 );
$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir3 ));

class DirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator{
    public function accept(){
        $excludes = "/_thumbs";
        return !(in_array($this->getFilename(), $excludes));
    }
}

$filterItr = new DirFilter($iterators);

$rgIt = new RegexIterator($filterItr, "/^.+\.jpg$/i");
$files = iterator_to_array($rgIt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative assertion in your regexp pattern:

```
...
$rgIt = new RegexIterator($iterators, "/(?!\/_thumbs\/)^.+\.jpg$/i"); 
$files = iterator_to_array($rgIt);
...
```

If the above doesn't work for you, try using `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator` to filter out "thumb" images :

```
$filter = function ($file, $key, $iterator) {
    if ($iterator->hasChildren() && $file->getFilename() == "_thumbs") {
        return true;
    }
    return $file->isFile();
};
...
$iterators->append( $dir2 );
$iterators->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($dir3, $filter)));
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is still processing the "_thumbs" directory inside $dir3 though.  Maybe the path needs to be more specific?  Maybe:
`"/(?!\/./parentfolder/_thumbs\/)^.+\.jpg$/i"` ?

Comment: @dotcommer, I've updated my post. Try another approach

Comment: Got it!  I just changed `== "_thumbs")` to `!= "_thumbs")` to filter out the thumbs directory.  Thank you very much for your help @RomanPerekhrest !